Regarding the issue of Blender importing FBX large files being too slow and often unresponsive
May I ask everyone, it always takes a long time for me to import FBX model files that exceed 150M or 200M in Blender, and I often encounter unresponsive situations? How can I solve this problem? First, rule out the configuration issue of the computer, as the CPU and memory never exceed 30% when importing. Do you have any recommended external plugins or solutions?

Hello, you're just running into the limitations of the software / hardware. Some (most) processes are inherently single threaded, so they will not overload your multi-core hardware and thus bottleneck the process. My recommendation is to break up the input file into smaller pieces and work locally. Blender is just not made for dealing with billions of triangles (unless instances are used). May I ask from which source the files come from ? How much triangles we're dealing with ? Or maybe you have very high res textures ?

@Gorgious,Hello,The model file size I previously processed was 256M with around 60000 objects, but more than half of them were empty. After deleting the objects, the total number of triangles was around 27000, and the total number of triangles was around 818000. The models I need to process are related to chemical engineering design, and they are all very simple, represented by cylindrical or square objects, but the quantity is too large.

@Gorgious,The computer I am using should not reach the performance bottleneck (i9+4090). When importing the fbx model, the CPU usage is only about 10%, and the memory may be relatively high, but it does not exceed 20GB.

Lets say you have a water tower tank with 8 output valves, and you want to fill a truck with a water tank. The tank on the truck only has one input valve. Do you think you can utilize the water tower tank outputs to their maximum capacity ? No, the bottleneck is the input valve. Here is the same thing happening, Blender is really bad with dealing with tens of thousands of objects, you could use the entirety of Amazon or Google cloud servers to import your file, it would not go any faster. There has been some improvements in the more recent Blender versions though. What versions are you using ?

@Gorgious,I am using Blender 3.4 version because Blender updates quickly, but changing to a new version requires reconfiguring my Blender settings and frequently used plugins, so I did not easily switch Blender versions
